# Get a list popular GitHub repositories for Swift Language

Tags: github-api

I want to list out the popular GitHub repositories for Swift and RXSwift language from GitHub API. Can any one help to get that list.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), look around, and read through the [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)? If you run into a specific problem, research it thoroughly, search thoroughly here, and if you're still stuck post your code and a description of the problem. Also, remember to include [Minimum, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). People will be glad to help

Answer (score 0):

you can try searching with the search term language:Swift language:and order by stars. Searching is descript https://developer.github.com/v3/search/

The http get request would look like:
https://api.github.com/search/repositories?q=language:Swift+language:RXSwift&sort=stars&order=desc